Using TouchEffect with a Button in Xamarin Forms / .NET MAUI
I have CollectionView with several items.
The items have same datatemplate, which consists of a stacklayout with a button.
    <CollectionView ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding SaveItems}"
                    SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="listItems:MyItemVM">
                <StackLayout TouchEffect.Command="{Binding SelectedItemCommand}"
                             TouchEffect.CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                    <Button Command={Binding OnCreateCommand} CommandParameter={Binding .} />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

When I press the Button, the Stacklayout is invoked instead, because it is higher in view hierarchy. How do I make it so I press outside the button it invokes the StackLayout command, and if I press the button is invokes the button command ?
I have tried multiple settings with InputTransparent, CascadeInputTransparent,  TouchEffect.ShouldMakeChildrenInputTransparent. I was expecting that InputTransparent = true resulted in both commands working but no. With InputTransparent = true either one works and the other doesn't, or vice-versa.
I have thought about using Skia renderer to detect touch position, or intercepting touch event in native code, but I hope there is an easier way with XAML.
EDIT: I managed to detect both commands with the following datatemplate:
<StackLayout>
  <Grid>
    <Grid TouchEffect.Command="{Binding SelectedItemCommand}"
                             TouchEffect.CommandParameter="{Binding .}" /> 
    <Grid>
         <Button Command={Binding OnCreateCommand} CommandParameter={Binding .} />
    </Gri>
  </Grid>
</StackLayout>

Because Grid content can overlay. It is not very performant but it works.

Do you mean you want to call the SelectedItemCommand when clicking outside the button of the StackLayout?

Yes, exactly. But I also want to call the OnCreateCommand when I press the button.

Can you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example to help me reproduce your problem?

SOLVED: I managed to detect both commands with the following datatemplate:
<StackLayout>
  <Grid>
    <Grid TouchEffect.Command="{Binding SelectedItemCommand}"
                             TouchEffect.CommandParameter="{Binding .}" /> 
    <Grid>
         <Button Command={Binding OnCreateCommand} CommandParameter={Binding .} />
    </Gri>
  </Grid>
</StackLayout>

Because Grid content can overlay. It is not very performant but it works.
